# Linux 4.18, struct usb_device no longer have children[USB_MAXCHILDREN]

Tags: c, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I have an old USB Kernel Module driver code for kernel 2.6.x and now I need to port over to newer kernel 4.18.x and I found out that in usb.h, struct usb_device does not have this field children[USB_MAXCHILDREN] anymore. So this breaks my code.

Basically my code needs to do some "routing" search to get the device routing path by traversing the "children" field. Is there an alternative way to do that?

Below is snippet of my code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROUTE GetRoute ( struct usb_device * dev )
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  returns route encoded as:    Bus, RootHubPort,Hub1Port,Hub2Port,Hub3Port,Hub4Port,Hub5Port
// 
//    bit numbers in 32-bit word 31-24   23-20     19-16    15-12    11-8     7-4      3-0
//
//    where Bus is 8 bits (1 based), and Hub ports are 4 bits (1-based with 000 meaning leaf node)
//
//    thus a route of all zeros is invalid - and is used to indicate an error
{  
  int i, Port, PortIndex;
  unsigned long shift;
  #define MAX_DEPTH 6 // (including root hub)
  ROUTE u32Route = 0x00000000;
  
  struct usb_device *currentdev;
  struct usb_device *DevsReverseChain[ MAX_DEPTH + 1];  // we put our own dev in here too  - so needs + 1
  int nLevels = 0;  
  
  int PortArray[MAX_DEPTH] = {0}; 
  int PortArrayIndex = 0;

  // build up array of devs till we reach root 
  currentdev = dev;
  for (nLevels = 0; nLevels <= MAX_DEPTH; nLevels++)
  {  
    DevsReverseChain[ nLevels ] = currentdev;
    if (currentdev == currentdev->bus->root_hub)
    {
      //TRACE("GetRoute: got back to root hub, nLevels=%d", nLevels);
      break;
    } 
    currentdev = currentdev->parent; 
  }  
  
  if (nLevels > MAX_DEPTH)                                                   
  {
    ERROR("GetRoute: too many hub levels (MAX I can handle is %d)", MAX_DEPTH);
    return 0; // 0=invalid route
  }
  
  // we now know how many levels there are between root dev and target dev
  // so we can start filling in an array of the port number sequence to get
  // back to the device from the root hub
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  PortArrayIndex = 0;
  for (i = nLevels; i > 0; i--)
  {  
    // Locate port on which our next device down resides
    Port = 0;  // init to invalid
    for(PortIndex=0; PortIndex<8; PortIndex++)
    {
      if ( DevsReverseChain[i]->children[PortIndex] == DevsReverseChain[i-1] )
      {  
        Port = PortIndex + 1;  // linux portnums are 0-based - OURS ARE 1-based!!!!!
        //printk("TRACE GetRoute: good child port=%d\n", Port);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (Port != 0)
    { 
      PortArray[PortArrayIndex] = Port; 
      PortArrayIndex++;           
    }
    else
    {
      ERROR("GetRoute: logic error 1 - failed to re-find child from parentlevel %d", i);
      return 0; // 0=invalid route
    }
  }  
  
  // we now know everything we need, so we can encode the route information into u32Route
  // - from the MSB - bus/roothub end
  u32Route = 0x00000000;
  
  u32Route += dev->bus->busnum << 24;  // top byte is bus number (1-based !!)
  
  shift = 20;    // bottom 6 nibbles are the port numbers on the (up to) 6 hubs
  for (i = 0; i < nLevels; i++)
  {             
    u32Route += PortArray[i] << shift;
    shift -= 4;
  }  
  
  //TRACE("GetRoute: final u32Route=0x%lx", u32Route);
      
  return u32Route;
}
```

Comment: There is a `struct usb_device *usb_hub_find_child(struct usb_device *hdev, int port1)` function, where `hdev` is the hub USB device and `port1` is a 1-based port number. There is also a `usb_hub_for_each_child(hdev, port1, child)` macro to iterate over all children of a hub USB device `hdev`, where `port1` will get set to the 1-based port number of the child and `child` will point to the child USB device.

Comment: `git log -G children -- drivers/usb` will give the list of commits that have touched the lines that have word `children` in the _drivers/usb/_ folder. You can read the commit messages that should explain what happened.